# Javascript array mess

Tags: javascript

jAs a result coming from a request, I have a splitted string consisting of the following elements  (javascript). The string consists of three repetitions pf the same sequence of attributes.

```
var str_before_split="name1_address_telephone,name2_address_telephone,name3_address_telephone";
```

Splitting the separate strings on the comma gives me an array consisting of 3 different strings. So, in order to complete the splitting, I used: (where limit=3, the number can vary)

```
for(var i=0; i<limit; i++) {  var everyString=separator[i].split("_"); //I checked each array position and is storing like charm.}
```

The problem occured when I wanted to create three different arrays for the three different categories. So, inside the initial for loop, we have:( I post the loop again)

```
var les=limit*3; //to see the maximum possible elements of the array

for(var i=0; i<limit; i++) {  var everyString=separator[i].split("_"); 


for(var j=0; j<les; j+3)
           {
         name[i]=everyString[j];
}

   for( j=3; i<les; j+3)
           {
         address[i]=everyString[j];
}

  for( j=6; i<les; j+3)
           {
         tel[i]=everyString[j];
}


}
```

Whenever running on the page though, the script freezes. No mistake is appearing on my JS error detection plugin. I tried alerting the arrays inside the small for loops and even the right result appears, the alert window won't stop appearing over and over again. Any hints?

Comment: Any specific reason you're using 3 arrays over a single array of object?

Comment: Why `i+3`? What would that do?

Comment: you have a missing closing braces.
`for(var i=0; i<limit; i++) {  var everyString=separator[i].split("_");} //I checked each array position and is storing like charm.` In your code you have it in the comment

Comment: because I want to assign the elements on different categories later.

Comment: the first loop will never end, check your loop definitions

Comment: @stackErr this one only happened here as I was copying, but thanks

Comment: @IgorDymov, but in the previous code there is a specific value given for the limit variable. I just didn't mention it here

Comment: That's some weird brace formatting...

Comment: @brbtsl: `for(var j=0; j<les; i+3)` i meant this

Comment: i realized after... even if i changed to j+3 i was distracted not using+=3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(var j=0; j<les; i+3)
           {
         name[i]=everyString[j];
}
```

That says, "Set `j` to `0`. Every time through the loop, check `j` is less than `les`. Then evaluate `i+3` (a different variable), ignore the result and leave `j` alone." You have an infinite loop, because `j` is never anything other than `0`, and so will always be less than `les`.

You need something like this:

```
for(var j=0; j<les; j+=3)
           {
         name[i]=everyString[j];
}
```

Comment: No, i does not get incremented here.

Comment: @CBroe Indeed, I had already modified my answer.

Comment: Well, I am so sad there is only one answer, and i feel so dumb about forgetting the +=3 expression. @^$^#$&@^*@

Answer (score 5):

It's an infinite loop:

```
for(var j=0; j<les; i+3)
```

The loop variable isn't incremented here. `i+3` does nothing, and by the way the variable should be j, not `i`.

Use this line:

```
for(var j=0; j<les; j++)
```

But I think you have to rethink the whole thing. If I'm not mistaken, you just want to have arrays of all the names, of all the addresses and all the telephone numbers:

```
var separator = str_before_split.split(",");
for(var i=0; i < separator.length; i++) {
    var everyString=separator[i].split("_"); 
    name[i]=everyString[0];
    address[i]=everyString[1];
    tel[i]=everyString[2];
}
```

Comment: Or possibly `...; j+=3)`, though it's hard to tell.

Comment: @MaxArt and RichieHindle .. going to try this, i wanted a step of 3 each time, so that's why the loop is infinite, you are right ;) i+3 was due to being in a hurry writing. But since I won't be able to know the length of the groups in the string each time, that's why i used the 3 different for loops

Answer (score 4):

Apart from i being the wrong variable if your break condition is based on j:

```
for(var j=0; j<les; i+3)
```

`i+3` does not change the value of `i` – so your for loops run forever (well just the first one does, because the other two don’t even get a chance to be executet).